# Equivalent of getBufferedPosition() in exoplayer for iOS AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I am currently developing an avplayer app which calculates HLS streaming metrics. I wanted to get buffer level for the current item.

```html
private var availableDuration: Double {
        guard let timeRange = player.currentItem?.loadedTimeRanges.first?.timeRangeValue else {
            return 0.0
        }
        let startSeconds = timeRange.start.seconds
        let durationSeconds = timeRange.duration.seconds
        return startSeconds + durationSeconds
    }
```

I am a little confused in the terminology used in apple documentations.

Here i am getting availableDuration of the current item but i am not sure if this represents the buffer level of the current item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems ok. I used same

```
var bufferInSeconds: Double {
  guard let range = self.loadedTimeRanges.first?.timeRangeValue else { 
    return 0.0 
  }
  let sec = range.start.seconds + range.duration.seconds
  return sec >= 0 ? sec : 0
}
```